# Random redirect and Cart erase - cookie possible issue?

Tags: magento, cookies

I have moved my site from non-www to www but now I have got some problems since sometimes I got random redirects to the homepage and cart is erased(I'm using magento), so I thought to relate this problem to cookies: since I would like to create a cookieless domain that serves static content from sub-domains I have set as `cookie domain`: `www.example.com` but if I take a look at the cookies through firefox firebug I see: `.www.example.com`, could this be the problem? Other hint about where I should search? Is a problem related to cookie lifetime?

**EDIT**
This is how I redrect from htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^farmaciacaloini\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.farmaciacaloini.com/shop/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**EDIT 2**
`Cookie lifetime` is set to `86400` and now I have just changed `Session timeout` to the same value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend setting it to ".example.com" mainly because it depends upon how you set the redirect from non-www to www.

Comment: Hi, I have added the redirect code that I use in htaccess

Comment: Are you sure, this happened when you did this change? My first initial thoughts are problems with a short session.

Comment: I have also changed(yesterday) the cookie lifetime to 86400, it happened again, maybe an old cooki, I will do more test. If it is a problem related to some lifetime, can I switch back to the www one?

Comment: Also changed session timeout to 86400

Comment: You could maybe check out this post,   I'd post what I think as my answer in here,  but there's so many possibilities.  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/385/cart-dropping-all-items-cart-session-clears